# Arredondar resultado no script

Tags: javascript

Nesse meu script como posso arredondar meu resultado? Estou tentando usar o `(total.toFixed(2));` mais não funciona.

```
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="resultado" />

function updateValue(){
    //atualiza os valores
    inputQtd = parseFloat(document.getElementById("qtd").value);
    inputValor = parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor").value);
    inputMark = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mark").value);

    //atualiza o valor no resultado
    var total = document.getElementById("total");

    total.value = (inputQtd * inputValor ) / inputMark;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No teu código `total` é um elemento certo? então não podes fazer `total.toFixed(2)`. Quanto muito podes fazer

```
total.value = total.value.toFixed(2)
```

Mas o melhor seria fazer antes de escrever no DOM:

```
 total.value = ((inputQtd * inputValor ) / inputMark).toFixed(2);
```

Exemplo:

```
var inputQtd = 145.3445;
var inputValor = 45.45;
var inputMark = 5.65;

var numero = ((inputQtd * inputValor ) / inputMark).toFixed(2);
alert(numero); // dá 1169.19
```